# Переменная в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив вида

```
Array
(
    [query] =&gt; Array
        (
            [pages] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [102] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [pageid] =&gt; 102
                            [ns] =&gt; 0
                            [title] =&gt; Product Title
                            [contentmodel] =&gt; wikitext
                            [pagelanguage] =&gt; ru
                            [touched] =&gt; 2016-01-13T13:51:08Z
                            [lastrevid] =&gt; 108
                            [length] =&gt; 5
                            [new] =&gt; 
                            [starttimestamp] =&gt; 2016-01-14T16:44:54Z
                            [edittoken] =&gt; 27a853a34ac085794aebd5966aed927f5697d086+\
                            [revisions] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [0] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [timestamp] =&gt; 2016-01-13T13:51:08Z
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

В итоге получаю edittoken таким образом: `$token['query']['pages']['102']['edittoken']`

`102` может меняться, т.е. `$token['query']['pages']['произвольный_номер']['edittoken']` надо получить

Comment: на этом уровне всегда один элемент или может быть несколько?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на этом уровне всегда один элемент

```
array_values($token['query']['pages'])[0]['edittoken']
```

Comment: current. http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Для одного элемента:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

```
<?php

$a = ["b" => ["c" =>"aaaaa"]];

echo current($a)["c"];
// Непомню точно версию но может понадобиться:
$q = current($a);
echo $q["c"];

// В ваше случае:
echo current($token['query']['pages'])['edittoken']
```